# How I can launch instagram desktop app present in Virtual machine by using playwright typescript code?

Tags: virtual-machine, playwright

```
`async  getInstaWindowsSession(): Promise<any> {
    console.log("VM started...");
    const { chromium } = devices;

    const labSettings = {
        platformName: Lab[accessdata.labName].instagram.platformName,
        deviceName: Lab[accessdata.labName].instagram.deviceName,
        app: Lab[accessdata.labName].instagram.app,
        vmUrl: Lab[accessdata.labName].instagram.vmUrl
    };

    try {
        const cap = {
            platformName: labSettings.platformName,
            deviceName: labSettings.deviceName,
            app: labSettings.app
        };



        const browser = await playwright.chromium.connect({
        wsEndpoint: labSettings.vmUrl ,
            ...cap// Use appropriate connection details here
        });

        const context = await browser.newContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();
        await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');

        // Perform actions with first session
        // ...
        const desktopCapabilities = {
            platformName: labSettings.platformName,
            deviceName: labSettings.deviceName,
            app: 'Root'
        };
        const desktopsession = await playwright.chromium.connect({
            wsEndpoint: labSettings.vmUrl ,
            ...desktopCapabilities// Use appropriate connection details here
        });


        const desktopContext = await desktopsession.newContext();
        const desktopPage = await desktopContext.newPage();
        //  await desktopPage.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
        const MAWebElement = await desktopPage.$('Instagram - Shortcut');
        const MAWinHandleStr = await MAWebElement?.getAttribute('NativeWindowHandle');
        const MAWinHandleInt = parseInt(MAWinHandleStr || '', 10);
        const MAWinHandleHex = MAWinHandleInt.toString(16);

        const MACapabilities = {
            platformName: labSettings.platformName,
            deviceName: labSettings.deviceName,
            appTopLevelWindow: MAWinHandleHex
            };`
```

Above code I have written but getting below issue

```
<ws connect error> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub WebSocket was closed before the connection was established
<ws disconnected> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub code=1006 reason=
============================================================
    at InstagramCustomerPage.getInstaWindowsSession (D:\CodeBase\playwright\Pages\InstagramCustomerPage.ts:82:65)
    at World.<anonymous> (D:\CodeBase\playwright\step-definitions\InstagramStepDefination.ts:16:56)
    at wrapPromiseWithTimeout (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\time.ts:55:10)
    at Object.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.ts:86:16)
    at Object.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\step_runner.ts:50:20)
    at TestCaseRunner.invokeStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:134:12)
    at TestCaseRunner.runStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:331:20)
    at D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:237:34
    at TestCaseRunner.aroundTestStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:167:28)
    at TestCaseRunner.runAttempt (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:215:7)
    at TestCaseRunner.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:185:29)
    at Runtime.runTestCase (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\index.ts:89:20)
    at Runtime.start (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\index.ts:116:7)
    at runCucumber (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\api\run_cucumber.ts:125:19)
    at Cli.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\index.ts:78:25)
    at Object.run [as default] (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\run.ts:38:14) {
    name: 'Error'
    }
    [2023-12-27T13:47:01.614Z] Error connecting to Instagram: browserType.connect: WebSocket error: ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub 404 Not Found
    =========================== logs ===========================
    <ws connecting> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub
    <ws unexpected response> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub 404 Not Found
    <ws error> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub error WebSocket was closed before the connection was    established
    <ws connect error> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub WebSocket was closed before the connection was established
    <ws disconnected> ws://10.133.78.239:4723/wd/hub code=1006 reason=
============================================================
    at InstagramCustomerPage.getInstaWindowsSession (D:\CodeBase\playwright\Pages\InstagramCustomerPage.ts:82:65)
    at World.<anonymous> (D:\CodeBase\playwright\step-definitions\InstagramStepDefination.ts:16:56)
    at wrapPromiseWithTimeout (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\time.ts:55:10)
    at Object.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.ts:86:16)
    at Object.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\step_runner.ts:50:20)
    at TestCaseRunner.invokeStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:134:12)
    at TestCaseRunner.runStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:331:20)
    at D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:237:34
    at TestCaseRunner.aroundTestStep (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:167:28)
    at TestCaseRunner.runAttempt (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:215:7)
    at TestCaseRunner.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:185:29)
    at Runtime.runTestCase (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\index.ts:89:20)
    at Runtime.start (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\index.ts:116:7)
    at runCucumber (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\api\run_cucumber.ts:125:19)
    at Cli.run (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\index.ts:78:25)
    at Object.run [as default] (D:\CodeBase\playwright\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\run.ts:38:14) {
  name: 'Error'
`

In Virtual Machine I am getting below error 

`GET /wd/hub HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 10.133.78.239:4723
Sec-WebSocket-Key: y54eUeLcEKQoTOqsqL937A==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Playwright/1.32.0 (x64; windows 10.0) node/20.9
x-playwright-browser: chromium
x-playwright-proxy:


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```